# Constantes enum estáticas

Tags: java, enums, static

```
    enum Animals {
     DOG("woof"), CAT("meow"), FISH("burble");
     String sound;
     Animals(String s) { sound = s; }
     }
     class TestEnum {
      static Animals a;
      public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(a.DOG.sound + " " + a.FISH.sound);
     }
   }
```

Não entendi porque o código acima compila normalmente. A constante do tipo enum "Animals" é declarada sem nenhuma inicialização, não deveria ocorrer uma exceção nullpointer? Isso não ocorre pelo fato de ser declarado como estático? Como isso ocorre?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Daria `NullPointerException` se fosse `a.sound`.

É estranho, mas, ao fazer `a.DOG.sound` você está acessando `DOG` estaticamente como se fosse `Animals.DOG.sound`.

De forma geral, o Java permite acessar membros estáticos, atributos ou métodos, através de variáveis de uma instância. Um enum é apenas um caso mais específico onde cada constante funciona um atributo estático.

Da mesma forma, por exemplo, `MinhaClasse.metodoEstatico()` pode também ser executado com `meuObjeto.metodoEstatico()`, mesmo quando `meuObjeto = null`.

O Java, sabendo o tipo da variável, consegue identificar o membro estático e executar. Como ele não precisa do `this` para referenciar a instância não ocorre `NullPointerException`.

Na prática:

```
class PegadinhaDeCertificacao {
    static void metodo() {
        System.out.println("Ha! Pegadinha do Malandro!!");
    }
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Test a = null;
        a.metodo();
    }
}
```

O código acima vai imprimir o texto normalmente e não vai lançar exceção alguma.

Mais uma vez, é um comportamento contra-intuitivo e, portanto, **não é recomendado acessar membros estáticos usando variáveis de instância**.

Boas IDEs e analisadores de código emitirão alertas ao encontrar tais situações.

Answer (score 2):

Conforme o [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9) da documentação da Oracle, um enumerador não possui mais instâncias além daquelas definidas por suas constantes.

Em uma [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32354107/how-are-enums-internally-represented-in-java) no SO inglês, cada classe enum é compilada como sublcasse de `java.lang.Enum`, e cada constante torna-se `static final`.

Em linha de comando, pode-se executar a linha `javap -p -c NomeDaClasse`, como NomeDaClasse referente ao seu arquivo `.class`.

Outro link da documentação para referência: [Enum Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)